# Why can't reset password for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, password

I can login postgresql database without password :

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Now i want to reset password 'xxxxxxxx' for postgres:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxx';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
sudo passwd -d postgres
passwd: password expiry information changed.
sudo -u postgres passwd
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Now restart postgresql:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

issu1:can't login postgres with `xxxxxxxx`:

```
psql -d postgres  -U postgres  -W
Password: 
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

issu2:why can still login postgres with user postgres without password?

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: `sudo passwd -d postgres` changes the password of the **Linux** user, not the database user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file has a rule mandating that when a local connection is attempted with the `postgres` database user, it gets through if the local OS user doing it is `postgres` too. That is the `peer` authentication method. With this method, the password is not asked for, and ignored if you supply it anyway (the  `-W` option).

That explains both the issues #1 and #2.

The solution is to configure `pg_hba.conf`. Replacing the `peer` method with `md5` or `scram-sha-256` (if you're on a recent Postgres version) would require a password even for local connections, which seems like what you want.